# Can the gauge boson respective of a spontaneously broken generator remain massless in the context of the Higgs Mechanism?

Tags: gauge-theory, group-theory, higgs, symmetry-breaking, beyond-the-standard-model

I'm studying a 3-3-1 model which is an extension of the standard model. The breaking $$SU(3)\times U(1) \to SU(2)\times U(1)'$$ occurs in a single step and through a single scalar VEV.

The problem is that implementing this model on Mathematica, evaluating the scalar covariant derivatives, assembling the vector mass matrix and diagonalizing it, I find that only 3 vector bosons acquire mass, not the 5 that would be expected realizing that $$\text{dim}[SU(3)\times U(1)]-\text{dim}[SU(2)\times U(1)']=5.$$

Assuming that my calculations are correct, is it possible that $$SU(3)\times U(1) \to SU(2)\times U(1)'$$ is indeed the breaking pattern caused by the vacuum of that single scalar even if the bosons remains massless or is the final symmetry strictly bigger than the one stated?

Comment: Unlikely… can you monitor the two rogue gauge fields and the two Goldstone bosons with *identical* quantum numbers?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I just came here to answer my own question or close it: what you say is exactly what happened. The adjoint eigenstates were classified as zero mass because I had not symmetrized the matrix with regard to 'conjugation of the basis' and they are charged. After symmetrization the two missing massive partners became apparent. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: *No,* that is not possible under normal circumstances.

1. Let us for simplicity consider the [spontaneous symmetry breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking) (SSB) of the group
   $$ G~=~ U(N+1) \quad \longrightarrow\quad H~=~ U(N), $$
   i.e. there are $$
   \dim_{\mathbb{R}} G-\dim_{\mathbb{R}} H~=~ (N+1)^2-N^2~=~2N+1$$ broken generators.
2. At the [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) level this corresponds to OP's example for $N=2$ and to [electroweak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction) SSB for $N=1$ because$^1$ $$u(N)\cong su(N)\oplus u(1), \qquad u(N\!+\!1)\cong su(N\!+\!1)\oplus u(1).$$
   This is good enough to count [DOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom)s.
3. Let the scalar field $\Phi$ transform in the fundamental/defining representation $V\cong \mathbb{C}^{N+1}$ of $G$. Assume that it has a non-zero [VEV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_expectation_value) $\Phi_0\neq 0$.
   To be concrete, by a global $G$ transformation we may assume that
   $$\Phi_0~\propto~ \begin{pmatrix}
   0\cr \vdots \cr 0 \cr 1 \end{pmatrix}~\in~V.$$
4. The [stabilizer/isotropy subgroup](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stabilizer+group) is
   $$H~\cong~\begin{pmatrix} H \cr & 1   \end{pmatrix}_{(N+1)\times (N+1)} ~ \subseteq~G. $$
5. In the unitary gauge$^2$ we may assume that the scalar field (including quantum fluctuations) is of the form
   $$\Phi ~\in~ \{0\}^N\times \mathbb{R}, $$
   i.e. there is only 1 real physical Higgs boson. The remaining $2N+1$ fluctuations are eaten by gauge symmetry (along the broken directions).
6. The mass terms for the gauge fields come from the Lagrangian term $|D_{\mu}\Phi_0|^2$. This makes precisely $2N+1$ components of the gauge fields $A_{\mu}\in \mathfrak{g}=u(N\!+\!1)$ massive, namely the ones in the last column.

--

$^1$ $SU(1)=\{1\}$ and $su(1)=\{0\}$ are singletons.

$^2$ The [unitary gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarity_gauge) is here a partial [gauge fixing condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing) that fixes the gauge symmetry along the broken directions. Ultimately we should also fix the $H$-gauge symmetry, but that's another story.